# My Javascript code doesn't work - Jquery selector issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I copied a piece of code from the coding book, instead of downloading Jquery environment, I add a google host.
But when I click the button, the object does not move. Would anyone please tell me why.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery goes to DOM-ville</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" ></script>
<style>
    #change_me {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 400px;
        font: 24px arial;
    }

    #move_up #move_down #color #disappear{
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body>
    <button id = "move_up">Move Up</button>
    <button id = "move_down">Move Down</button>
    <button id = "color">Change Color</button>
    <button id = "disappear">Disappear/Re-appear</button>

    <div id = "change_me">Make Me Do Stuff!</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("move_up").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
            });
            $("move_down").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").animate({top:500},2000);
            });
            $("#color").click(function(){
                $("change_me").css("color","purple");
            });
            $("disappear").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your listener `move_up` should be `#move_up` same with `move_down`

Comment: Thank you very much, really a careless mistake from a beginner. While the debugger just didn't show me about that syntax error orz.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is bad at this. I’d say avoid it, but, you’re making a jQuery animation showcase, so… =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the '#' prefix for id's:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery goes to DOM-ville</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" ></script>
<style>
    #change_me {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        left: 400px;
        font: 24px arial;
    }

    #move_up #move_down #color #disappear{
        padding: 5px;
    }
</style>


</head>

<body>
    <button id = "move_up">Move Up</button>
    <button id = "move_down">Move Down</button>
    <button id = "color">Change Color</button>
    <button id = "disappear">Disappear/Re-appear</button>

    <div id = "change_me">Make Me Do Stuff!</div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#move_up").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
            });
            $("#move_down").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").animate({top:500},2000);
            });
            $("#color").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").css("color","purple");
            });
            $("#disappear").click(function(){
                $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
            });
        });
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Here's your fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sXT35/)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you're referencing your elements with a `#`.

Try changing your javascript to the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#move_up").click(function(){
            $("#change_me").animate({top:30},200);
        });
        $("#move_down").click(function(){
            $("#change_me").animate({top:500},2000);
        });
        $("#color").click(function(){
            $("#change_me").css("color","purple");
        });
        $("#disappear").click(function(){
            $("#change_me").toggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You need the`#` if you're referencing an element by it's `id`, and you need a `.` if you're referencing it by it's `class`.

It's also best practice to reference the jQuery without the protocol like so:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```